# execute php after json output

Tags: php, json

i am sending few data as json from php file and it works without any issue. but i want to keep executing php file after json output. if i comment this line then those php codes are executing else they are not executing.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
 some more code here
   exit(json_encode($response));
```

next is few more php codes which makes database connection and executes.

```
   $res2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `tableA` where status='0' order by id desc limit 5");
```

update code and change the status to 1
if i comment below code

```
      exit(json_encode($response));
```

then update code works and updates the status to 1 else it is 0. mainly because its a json file as per header and it advises to close the script execution after exit code. i tried toset header as none and echo the output but it does not work. i tried to flush also. it did not work either. any idea will be great

Comment: It seems you are mistaken [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) for [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). Use `echo()` to display a text (send it back to the browser). Use `exit()` to terminate the script's execution at that point (`exit()` never returns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use echo instead of exit

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

exit will terminate code at that line.

Comment: echo is not json formatted. in chrome browser response and preview shows same when i use echo but it shows formatted code when i use exit

Comment: json doesn't need to be formatted ("prettyJson") for js to be unsterstood.

Comment: unable to display in browser however i can see in console

Comment: can you paste output with exit & json?

Comment: @PraveenPK i can see echo gives two set of data and exit gives one set of data. posting in few minutes if failed to find out

Comment: @PraveenPK working with echo.it was my problem as i had two set of data,.thankss

Comment: @PraveenPK is it possible to throw partial data through json. i have foreach and i am sending total data after all rows are done. it is ok for 5-10 rows but when rows are 100 it take much time, it will be better if i can send partial data say 10 rows each time till end through json. any idea?

Comment: @bijoy no. you can use pagination or custom queries to get partial data.

Comment: @PraveenPK custome queries for partial data. any example /tutorial/links plz

Comment: @bijoy i just mean that you should customise your query using limit. there is no way to echo it with for each

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear but from what I figure out, you want to send output to browser "real time" and not wait for the script to finish. Still you are using `exit`, which will end the script. You should `echo` instead and flush output immediately.

e.g.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
//some more code here
echo(json_encode($response));

// This is what you need
ob_flush();
flush();

// Even more code
echo(json_encode($anotherResponse));
```

Comment: echo is not json formatted. in chrome browser response and preview shows same when i use echo but it shows formatted code when i use exit so it is not coming in browser however i can see in consol

Comment: Can you please paste the output?